# Split a string with , and split a string even no , present in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column and i need to split a column with "," and even if no "," present in the value.

```
Value
=====
59.5

59.5, 5

60

60,5
```

desired output

```
value1  value2

======  ======

59.5

59.5      5

60        

60        5
```

Tried the code but getting an below error:

df['value1'], df_merge['value2'] = df['value'].str.split(',', 1).str

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could search for "," first and only do the split if str contains ",".

Comment: Can you write it in the code format pls for my above dataframe column ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the string method `str.partition`. It returns a 3 tuple every time with what's on the left of your chosen partition (you would choose a comma) and whats to the right of it.

df['value1'], _, df_merge['value2'] = str(df['value']).partition(',')

Comment: Can you write it in the code format pls ?

Comment: Tried the above code, but the got the below error:   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Did you included the underscore?